# How use SQL to select random sample of x from larger dataset?

Tags: sql-server

There's a dataset of about 5000 rows, with 5 columns each. Each RowID, has four dimensions Date, Location, Department, Funding. An example of a few rows is listed below. I'm looking at generated a percentage of sample rows say 200 out of the 5000. The challenge is to have it be a proportional representative of the four dimensions. Meaning, the stratification across these four dimensions on the sample of 200 stays (as reasonably) same as the larger population of 5000.

I've ran partition by, order by to choose random percentage - but would like to see if there's an optimal and better method.

```
RowID, Date     Location,  Department, Funding
1,     Jan 2018, Ohio,     Math,       Yes
2,     Jan 2018, New York, Math,       Yes
3,     Feb 2018, Ohio,     Engineering No
4,     Feb 2018, Arizona,  Math,       Yes
5,     Mar 2018, Ohio,     Engineering Yes
```

Comment: Not really clear to me what you are trying to do here. Is this a single table and you just want a random 200 rows?

Comment: Yes @SeanLange. Random 200, but as proportional percentage of each of the dimensions.

Comment: What does that mean? Do you want 200 rows or a max of 200? And not sure what you mean by "dimensions" in this context. You have 5 columns in a single table. And how do you define the percentage you want returned? This likely isn't all that difficult but the question is just so vague.